# Can python sparse solve a few eigenvalues specified by index range?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I need to solve a few eigenvalues of a large matrix specified by their indices. These indices are according to the whole eigenspectrum sorted in algebraic (not absolute value) ascending order.

I notice this is made available by the subset_by_index option in [scipy.linalg.eigh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html), but not in, e.g., the sparse counterpart [eigsh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html). Is this possible at all in the sparse context?

Comment: Is the `which` keyword argument sufficient for your case? It seems to control selecting the largest/smallest in both magnitude and the algebraic sense.

Comment: @bnaecker No, I actually tried that. It's in fact very different from selection by index range. Very often, you get indices mixed if a parameter range is scanned for the matrix. And certainly, you have no idea of the exact info of the indices.